# XMLHttpRequest content-disposition null issue

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, .net, asp.net-core

This is my controller.

```
  [HttpGet("GetFile")]
        [Authorize]

        public async Task<FileContentResult> GetFile([FromQuery] Guid fileId)
        {
            var fileName = string.Format("{0}.doc", _service.GetFileNameFromId(fileId));
            var fileName = "someFile.doc";
            var mimeType = "application/msword";
            byte[] fileBytes = _service.GetFileByteArray(fileId);
            System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
            {
                FileName = fileName,
                Inline = false  
            };
            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
            return new FileContentResult(fileBytes, mimeType)
            {
                FileDownloadName = fileName
            };
        }
```

These are my response headers according to Swagger.

```
 content-disposition: attachment; filename="someFile.doc"; filename*=UTF-8''someFile.doc 
 content-length: 3853 
 content-type: application/msword 
 date: Thu31 Mar 2022 13:05:34 GMT 
 server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 
 x-powered-by: ASP.NET
```

But whenever I attempt to access the content-disposition header from Javascript, it returns null. I'm making an XMLHttpRequest.

```
 var contentDisposition = this.getResponseHeader('content-disposition');
```

Does my server-side code have any issues that could be causing this?

Comment: Can you share your JS code?

Answer (score 0):

Below is my work Post demo, you can refer to it.

FileAPIController.cs:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class FileAPIController : ControllerBase
{
    private IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment;

    public FileAPIController(IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment)
    {
        webHostEnvironment = _webHostEnvironment;
    }

    [HttpPost("UploadFile")]
    public async Task<string> UploadFile([FromForm] IFormFile file)
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(this.webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "IFiles/", file.FileName);
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
        System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
        {
            FileName = file.FileName,
            Inline = false
        };
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
        return "https://localhost:5001/IFiles/" + file.FileName;
    }
}
```

Privacy.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Privacy Policy";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<p>Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
<input type="file" id="File" />
<button id="AddButton" onclick="UploadFile()" type="submit">Add</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function UploadFile() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("POST", "https://localhost:5001/api/FileAPI/UploadFile", true);
 
        data = new FormData();
        data.append("file", document.getElementById("File").files[0]);
        xhttp.send(data);
 
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                 var disposition =xhttp.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
                alert(this.response);
            }
        };
    }
</script>
```

Result:

[image]